# Route with one param messing others

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I want acces user profile passing his slug with a param after site url like Twitter.

So i did it

```
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile'));
```

So I want to type http://mydomain.com/user1 and go to controller users, action profile and pass as param 'user1'.

Is working fine but is messing the other routes, for instance:

http://mydomain.com/comment/add

Tthe route is going to controller users and passing 'comment' like a param.

Comment: Of course this will mess with other routes, if you are using a wildcard on the top level.. Order matters, if you really must do it this way (and I highly recommend not doing this), put this route to the end of the routes file.

Comment: i understand that but, like my example "comments/add" is the default route of the cakephp to add some comment, this is not explicit in the route.php to me put it in the top of the wildcard route.

Answer (score 0):

### Put that route last

If you want to use a route of that kind it *must* be last, and you won't be able to use [Cake's default routes](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Config/routes.php) which are [included by default](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/Config/routes.php#L43). As such you'll need to explicitly route all controller and plugin routes first:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));

Router::connect('/:controller/', array('controller' => 'my|list|of|controllers', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/:controller/:action/*', array('controller' => 'my|list|of|controllers'));
...

Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile'));
```